# Iframe with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, dynamic

I need to build a page like this http://dojo.telerik.com/, everything works except the Javascript I give in the iframe. Basically I generate my complete page in HTML and give it to the iframe src attribute like this:

```
var content = '<html><head>'+headContent+'</head><body>'+bodyContent+'</body></html>';
document.getElementById('frame').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"+escape(content);
```

For example a "alert()" will work, but loading a js file like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

will not work, even if the file is local. I specify that all the js is in the head tag.

What happen? Is it the way I give the content to the iframe that is not correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you building an HTML document in script and then trying to hand it off to an iFrame?  My guess is that you are being shot down by security sandboxing.  Trying to load a script file into an iframe drawn from another domain is no doubt a very unsafe behavior destined for exploit; it is therefore likely disallowed.  What are you trying to accomplish with this scheme?

Comment: In fact there is two different mode in my page, the entire html mode and the body content only mode, in the second case I have to generate the html around this. I dont understand how Kendo proceed to make the js file load correctly. When I look at their code, it seems they give all the html directly to the iframe.

Comment: I have to admit you lost me.  I can't see any reason to ever try to hand html to an iFrame programmatically.  If you can build the HTML locally, there is no reason to be using an iFrame.

Comment: Sorry I am probably not very accurate.. In fact I need an iframe to "isolate" the content. The main page is running with a private angularjs framework and is supposed to allow people to test the different angularjs directives with different version of the framework, so I absolutely need an iframe to make this possible.. Basically the user choose in a select the version with which he wants to test the html he just typed. Do you understand?

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, but I doubt very much you can achieve it with a client side implementation.  If you want to reference cross-domain scripts like that, then you need to obtain the version information, collect the user's code, and direct the iFrame to a server side process that will build the HTML on the server.  It is probable that you cannot manipulate the SRC of an iFrame like that client side and hand off offsite content to it because it is an unsafe behavior and the browser will disallow it.

Comment: Try keeping the script references local (same domain) and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's the same problem with local script, that's why I was asking this question.. It's strange. I think you are right about the backend generation! However when I look on kendo there's no request when "runnning" :/

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the Kendo component that does this?